# Tomcat autodeploy working for one webapp and not the other

Tags: tomcat

I'm using tomcat5.5 (yeah it's old, I know, no choices there), and it contains 2 webapps. Both are deployed by putting a .war in the /webapps dir and letting tomcat do the rest. Both .war are generated the same way (automatic export from an Eclipse project), and both contains the same manifest, almost the same web.xml (the servlet names change of course), and no other fancy stuff.
My server.xml contains :

```
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
   unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
   xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" /> -->

    <Context path="/kernel"
    docBase="/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/kernelServlet/"
    debug="1"
    reloadable="true">
    <Environment name="graphsDir" value="/var/lib/tomcat5.5/graphs" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
</Context>

<Context path="/ff"
    docBase="/usr/share/tomcat5.5/webapps/ff/"
    debug="1"
    reloadable="true">
    <Environment name="databasePath" value="/var/lib/tomcat5.5/ffdb/database" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

In other words, it's pretty much the same for the two webapps. And I didn't find any other tomcat configuration files that contained something specific for one webapp.

And yet, the autodeploy for kernelServlet works (i just replace kernelServlet.war in the webapps dir, and tomcat changes the unpacked code in the webapps/kernelServlet/ dir), whereas it doesn't for ff (when i change the ff.war, nothing happens ; I have to tomcat restart for it to be deployed ; and I have to suppress the webapps/ff/ dir first too else nothing happens during the tomcat restart).

I don't know where to look, it seems to me that both webapps should behave exactly in the same way given this config.